# Java Streaming: get max if no duplicates

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to write a function that takes in a Map and returns an Entry.  If the entry with the max Integer value is unique, it should return that entry.  However, if there are duplicate entries with the same max value, it should return a new Entry with a key of "MULTIPLE" and a value of 0.  It's easy enough for me to get the max value ignoring duplicates:

```
public static Entry<String,Integer> getMax(Map<String,Integer> map1) {
    return map1.entrySet().stream()
                          .max((a,b) -> a.getValue().compareTo(b.getValue()))
                          .get();
}
```

But in order for me to do what I said initially, I could only find a solution where I had to create an initial stream to do a boolean check if there were multiple max values and then do another stream if not to get the value.  I'd like to find a solution where I can do both tasks with only one stream.

Here's my little test case:

```
   @Test
   public void test1() {
         Map<String,Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
         map1.put("A", 100);
         map1.put("B", 100);
         map1.put("C", 100);
         map1.put("D", 105);

         Assert.assertEquals("D", getMax(map1).getKey());

         Map<String,Integer> map2 = new HashMap<>();
         map2.put("A", 100);
         map2.put("B", 105);
         map2.put("C", 100);
         map2.put("D", 105);

         Assert.assertEquals("MULTIPLE", getMax(map2).getKey());
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem with two streams?  Why do you need to bring it down to one?

Comment: There's no problem. I just want to know if it's possible, and if so, how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple case of reduction, and you don't need any external libraries.

```
Map.Entry<String, Integer> max(Map<String, Integer> map) {
    return map.entrySet().stream()
            .reduce((e1, e2) -> {
                if (e1.getValue() == e2.getValue()) {
                    return new SimpleImmutableEntry<>("MULTIPLE", 0);
                } else {
                    return Collections.max(asList(e1, e2), comparingInt(Map.Entry::getValue));
                }
            })
            .orElse(new SimpleImmutableEntry<>("NOT_FOUND", 0));
}
```

Comment: Good idea, you don't need to: Collections.max(asList(e1, e2), comparingInt(Map.Entry::getValue)); e1.getValue() > e2.getValue() ? e1 : e2 will be good enough

Comment: that's funny... actually I think the answer is incorrect

Comment: How so? Now, I'm again filling in more characters for this comment.

Comment: Come on... I added the first comment because that one million temporary SimpleImmutableEntry/List will be created if the size of the map is one million. that's obvious and totally unnecessary. Secondly, again the answer is wrong, how? find it by yourself. your response is just not friendly and no need argue with you more

Comment: @123-xyz The OP didn't ask for a solution that performs for a large map, in which case several optimizations can be made. As for friendly, you're on the wrong site; try matchdotcom.

Comment: so what is wrong with this answer?  why do you say that it's incorrect?

Comment: you're just saying that he shouldn't be calling asList(), as it would be potentially creating a million Lists if there are a million items to compare...is that it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution by [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex)

```
public Entry<String, Integer> getMax(Map<String, Integer> map) {
    return StreamEx.of(map.entrySet()).collect(collectingAndThen(MoreCollectors.maxAll(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()),
            l -> l.size() == 1 ? l.get(0) : new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>("MULTIPLE", 0)));
}
```

Another solution is iterating the map twice with potential better performance:

```
public Entry<String, Integer> getMax(Map<String, Integer> map) {
    int max = map.entrySet().stream().mapToInt(e -> e.getValue()).max().getAsInt();

    return StreamEx.of(map.entrySet()).filter(e -> e.getValue().intValue() == max).limit(2)
            .toListAndThen(l -> l.size() == 1 ? l.get(0) : new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>("MULTIPLE", 0));
}
```

Comment: Hello. It has come to our attention that nearly all of your recent answers have been promoting the third-party library StreamEx. Overall, it looks like your answers are complete and relevant to the question, so thank you for trying to follow our guidelines. However, if you are affiliated with StreamEx in some way, you need to [disclose your affiliation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) explicitly in your answers. Otherwise, the community tends to perceive this as spamming or "astroturfing", which is unwelcome here.

Comment: I AM NOT affiliated with StreamEx. the only reason is just StreamEx is a great library, which could/should be used to resolve a lot of Java 8 stream API related questions

Comment: Cool. No worries, then. We just received some flags from users who were suspicious that nearly all of your answers were promoting this library. Maybe answer some other types of questions while you're at it? :-) Like I said, you're already doing well by showing *how* the library solves the problem, so keep up the good work.